# how to run the calibration using chessboardCorners

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to build a class that will run the calibration using a chessboard, my question is about the square-size, let say that the squares are 66mm, where should I put this info, in making ObjectPoints or where, my class is based on the example of the book *opencv2 computer vision application Programming cookbook*  and after checking the opencv example the put this value in build the objectspoints, here 's **part** of my code :

```
void Calibration::addPoints(const std::vector<cv::Point2f>&, const std::vector<cv::Point3f>&){
imagePoints.push_back(imageCorners);
objectPoints.push_back(objectCorners);
this->actualnumberOfFrames++;
if(actualnumberOfFrames == numberOfFrames){
    this->calibrate();
}
}

void Calibration::setImageCorners(cv::vector<cv::Point2f> corners, cv::Size board){
    actualBoardSize = board;
    imageCorners.clear();
    imageCorners = corners;
    objectCorners.clear();
    for (int i  = 0; i < board.height; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<board.width; j++){
            objectCorners.push_back(cv::Point3f(float(i*66),float(j*66),0.0f));  // is that correct 
        }
    }
    this->addPoints(imageCorners,objectCorners); 
}

double Calibration::calibrate(){
    return cv::calibrateCamera(this->objectPoints,this->imagePoints,this->theFrameSIZE,this->cameraMatrix,this->distortionCoeff,this->rvec,this->tvecs,this->flag);

      }
```

if you need more infos to understand the problem I'll explain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the object points should be known world coordinates, therefore you put the spacing in there. You could use any pattern you like, it does not even need to be a regular spacing, you just have to be able to detect it and know the world coordinates of the points relative to each other.